# Gerrit REST API, get user activity

Tags: rest, gerrit

I'm trying to monitor user commit activity (initial change commit or patching) in Gerrit using REST API.

Right now I have a working example that gets all changes per user using:**"changes/?q=owner:"** and lists one change for each user based on the latest change created date. The problem is that this method misses two things:

1. If a user commits a patch on a change created by the user itself, but on a different date compared to created date, this activity will not be caught.
2. If a user commits a patch on a change created by another user, this activity will not be caught. Worst case for this is that we have a user that never commits any own new initial changes, just working with patching other users initial changes.

Instead I would like to create a query in Gerrit like “give me all activities for user joe” and the look through the result for latest initial commit or patch activity.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "changes/?q=committer:xxxxx" instead:

```
committer:'COMMITTER'
    Changes where 'COMMITTER' is the committer of the current patch set.
```

See more info in the [Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#committer).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marcelo, you pointed me in the right direction. But I found that "owner" and "author" often is the same. But "committer" was the one that I needed. This catches both my number 1 and 2 issue!

Also if you want the commit date you have to add some options to your query:

```
changes/?q=committer:<USERID>&o=CURRENT_REVISION&o=CURRENT_COMMIT
```